# How to authenticate Token with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

I want to use devise' token_authenticatable helper to authenticate users against the system.

I found some older documentations where a method named valid_authentication_token?(...) is used but couldn't find the same in newer devise version.

So what's the right way to authenticate a user?
Should I request the Model for user with named token and checking if email-adresses match?

Thanks a lot for your help.

PascalTurbo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add

```
t.token_authenticatable
```

to you user ActionRecord, and add

```
devise  :token_authenticatable
```

to your User model

and specify which param is your token key in config/initializer/devise, something like this:

```
config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token
```

then controllers that use

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!  # Tell devise to use :user map
```

to authenticate. after the authenticate_user!, individual methods can test using

```
user_signed_in?
```

will authorize users either by the login session or the devise authorization token that is passed on the query string or passed using HTTP basic authentication. See Devise helper [code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) for details.

Comment: Are you sure that "load_and_authorize_resource" is part of devise? I couldn't find any documentation bout this - but a lot of entries for "cancan"

Comment: Sorry, mixed up my devise and cancan calls. We use both. I have updated my answer above with the before_filter authenticate_user! from Devise.

Comment: @SteveWilhelm You wrote ".. devise authorization token that is passed on the query string ...". Can you tell how I would do this when I send a POST request to a JSON API?

Comment: just pass the authentication token on as a URL param. I believe it defaults to auth_token and is configurable using config.token_authentication_key